# Atomic wait-then-take operation on number

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, synchronization, atomic

I have the following class:

```
public class AtomicLong
{
    private long initial;
    private long value;

    public AtomicLong(long value = 0)
    {
        this.initial = value;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public class Handle : IDisposable
    {
        private AtomicLong source;
        private long amount;

        public Handle(AtomicLong source, long amount)
        {
            this.source = source;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (source == null)
                return;
            Interlocked.Add(ref source.value, amount);
            source = null;
        }
    }

    public Handle Claim(long amount)
    {
        if (amount > initial)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount", amount, "Must be no more than the initial amount.");
        if (amount < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount", amount, "Must be nonnegative.");
        while (true)
        {
            var oldValue = Interlocked.Read(ref value);
            var newValue = oldValue - amount;
            if (newValue >= 0 &&
                oldValue == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, newValue, oldValue))
            {
                return new Handle(this, amount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example usage of this is that I can have a single `AtomicLong unusedMemory` which represents the current number of bytes of memory available to a set of workers. (It's not meant to be anywhere near exact - it's just a rough measure.) I then do this on a bunch of different worker threads:

```
while (true)
{
    var unitOfWork = WaitForUnitOfWork();
    long requiredMemory = unitOfWork.RequiredMemory;
    using (var handle = unusedMemory.Claim(requiredMemory))
    {
        //wait until requireMemory can be claimed from unusedMemory
        //do work with reserved memory, represented by handle
        //when handle disposes, memory is released back to the unusedMemory
    }
}
```

The problem with my `AtomicLong` class is that calls to `Claim` will busy-wait until they return. I'd like to fix this by using some kind of OS-level wait handle abstraction.

Can you suggest how I could go about doing that?

---

## Motivation

Consider the following scenario:

- unusedMemory starts with an initial value of 10GB (`10 << 30`)
- 100 worker threads
- 10 units of work, each taking 10GB and 1 minute to perform
- first worker calls `Claim(10 << 30)` and it nearly-immediately returns

  - it begins doing work that will finish after 1 minute
- some 9 other workers make an identical call to `Claim(10 << 30)` and do a "bad" busy wait for 1 minute

  - 9 threads doing something like a `while(true){/*do nothing*/}` loop in the `Claim` method!
  - lots of needless CPU usage
- the rest of the workers (90) do a "good" OS-level wait in the `WaitForUnitOfWork()` method

**The important point:** `Claim` is only "cheap" if the requested `amount` of memory is actually available to be claimed. If it isn't, busy-waiting happens until it is available.

Just to be entirely clear, in the `Claim` method, I'm pointing out the exact expression which makes all the difference (`newValue >= 0`):

```
while (true)
{
    var oldValue = Interlocked.Read(ref value);
    var newValue = oldValue - amount;
    if (newValue >= 0 && // <--------------------------- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
        oldValue == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, newValue, oldValue))
    {
        return new Handle(this, amount);
    }
}
```

The question is not about whether `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is going to be expensive - I'm aware it's cheap. The question is about how to deal with the busy-waiting that occurs in the case when the `amount` a caller wants to `Claim` is currently greater than the `amount` in the `AtomicLong`.

---

If you have a completely different approach to solving this kind of problem, or see some flaw in what I already have, I'd like to hear about that too!

Comment: I don't see anything there that looks like it will take a while.  Odds are any setup to allow asynchronous support would end up taking longer than a synchronous wait in virtually all conceivable instances.  It's probably not worth changing unless you have not yet added something that will end up taking a while.

Comment: @Servy So the thing I'm worried about is that if I have, say, 32 worker threads, because most units of work require very little memory, then I won't ever be waiting during `Claim` (great!). But in the somewhat-rare event that some really big units of work come in, such that only 3 or 4 workers should be running at once, I'll then have ~30 worker threads all busy waiting in `Claim`. That seems like it could be a problem - although I haven't profiled to verify that.

Comment: I agree with @Servy. Unless you are expecting an *extraordinary* level of write contention here, you're going to go through that loop once every time. Are you going to have an extraordinary amount of write contention?  My recommendation would be to do some benchmarks where you gather statistics on the average number of times you go through that loop in realistic situations, and only pursue a more complex solution if that number is large.

Comment: @TimothyShields So the key thing here is that a lock is only ever taken out long enough to do a very few, very fast operations.  Incrementing an int; a CPU can do that is just a handful of cycles.  The time it would take to stop the current thread and perform a context switch just once is going to potentially be many hundreds of cycles.  So you'd need to literally have several hundred threads trying to access this variable in the scope of a few microseconds for the lock contention to be so great that asynchrony is a win.  I just don't see that happening.

Comment: @EricLippert @Servy I think the subtle point you're missing is that it will be a likely scenario that `newValue < 0` in the `Claim` `while` loop for extended periods of time.  When some small subset of the workers have claimed all of the unusedMemory and the rest are sitting busy-waiting for memory to become available, they will be doing the equivalent of a `while (true) { do nothing }` loop. -- I have extended my question with an example.

Comment: @EricLippert My question was too large with not enough focus on the single part that was the big problem. Please take a closer look at the new part under the "Motivation" heading in my question. I hope you agree it's a more interesting question then it may have first appeared...

Comment: @TimothyShields: Got it. I agree, your motivating scenario is much more obvious now.  Is there a way to characterize your problem as a producer-consumer problem?  I'm thinking that a primitive like `AutoResetEvent` might be a good choice here since you can put the waiting threads to sleep and then "pulse" them when something happens that they might be interested in.

Comment: @EricLippert `ManualResetEvent`/`AutoResetEvent` were my first go-to for this problem, until I realized that when you `Set` one of those, *only one* of the `WaitOne` calls receives the signal. I need them *all* to receive the signal. I took a look at `Monitor.PulseAll` and `Monitor.Wait` but wasn't sure if they were right for this.

Comment: @EricLippert I added an answer that seems to work correctly. Does anything immediately appear wrong to you? I haven't used `Monitor` (explicitly) before.

Comment: @TimothyShields: That seems reasonable but I am actually not much of an expert on threading primitives. My advice is to post it on codereview.stackexchange.com and put links in between this question and your post on codereview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

## Parameters

- `obj`: the synchronization object used by `Monitor`
- `pollIterval`: the rate at which calls will poll until a successful transaction attempt
- `value`: the value being modified by the transaction
- `precondition`: an optional condition that must be true at the start of the transaction
- `transform`: the operation that changes the value
- `postcondition`: an optional condition that must be true at the end of the transaction

## Code

```
public static class AtomicHelper
{
    public static void LongTransaction(
        object obj,
        TimeSpan pollInterval,
        ref long value,
        Func<long, bool> precondition,
        Func<long, long> transform,
        Func<long, bool> postcondition)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var oldValue = Interlocked.Read(ref value);
            if (precondition != null && !precondition(oldValue))
            {
                Monitor.Wait(obj, pollInterval);
                continue;
            }
            var newValue = transform(oldValue);
            if (postcondition != null && !postcondition(newValue))
            {
                Monitor.Wait(obj, pollInterval);
                continue;
            }
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, newValue, oldValue) == oldValue)
            {
                Monitor.PulseAll(obj);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Example Usage

```
long n = 10;
object obj = new object();
//On many different threads, run this concurrently:
AtomicHelper.LongTransaction(
    obj,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    ref n,
    null,
    x => x - 1,
    x => x >= 0);
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
AtomicHelper.LongTransaction(
    obj,
    TimeSpan.Zero,
    ref n,
    null,
    x => x + 1,
    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

For instance, you can create a smarter busy-wait, by putting the active thread to sleep for a given time interval, so it doesn't always check your condition, but it does it periodically.

Another solution is to create a custom event and wait for that event in your active thread, and you can define a custom event which will fulfill your task I believe.

You can read more about events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx). You can read about custom event creation [here](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=685).